# How to put string variables into a Python array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, insert, append

I'm rather new at this (it's my first question ha!), and my english isn't as good and technical as yours so I apologize in advance. That being said, I'm trying to fit string variables to an array but I can't get it done. Here are the variables:

```
basket1 = {'vanilla wafers', 'bananas' , 'dog food'}
basket2 = {'bananas', 'bread', 'yogurt'}
basket3 = {'bananas','apples','yogurt'}
basket4 = {'vanilla wafers','bananas','whipped cream'}
basket5 = {'bread', 'vanilla wafers' , 'yogurt'}
basket6 = {'milk', 'bread', 'bananas'}
basket7 = {'vanilla wafers', 'apples' , 'bananas'}
basket8 = {'yogurt', 'apples', 'vanilla wafers'}
basket9 = {'vanilla wafers', 'bananas' , 'milk'}
basket10 =  {'bananas', 'bread', 'peanut butter'}
```

Any ideas? Should I use a list instead? It must have a 10x3 shape though.

Comment: You're right, you (and everyone else), have no need to apologize for their english. Do your best (as you've done) and hope for fair treatment. Anyone not giving fair treatment is failing in their compassion, and that isn't your fault.

Comment: Note: what you’re creating there are *sets*, not lists or arrays. In Python, a set is an unordered collection of items where each item can only appear once (so `{'apples', 'bananas', 'bananas'}` is the same as `{'bananas', 'apples'}`). Use `[]` to create a list instead (which is equivalent to an array in other languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the brackets with parentheses, so like this

```
basket1 = ['bread', 'cake', 'soap']
```

For multi-dimensional arrays, write

```
baskets = [['bread', 'cake', 'soap'], ['carrot', 'milk', 'wheat']]
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking more of a loop thing; I have a lot of those variables, all starting with 'basket' and they're consecutive. To be more specific, final array should be of nx3 shape.

Answer (score 0):

You could use declare a `baskets` list and iterate over a for loop to append values to the end of the list.

You can modify the `temp` list and fill it with values accordingly each time.

```
baskets = list()

for i in range(n):
   temp = [value1,value2,value3]
   baskets.append(temp)

print(baskets)
```